# Have cmake modify object files before linking static library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am really new to cmake but I am trying to see if there is a way to modify object files that cmake has made before linking them into a static library.  My cmake file looks like this right now:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")    
set(SOURCES
    file1.cpp 
    file2.cpp
)
add_library(my_proj STATIC ${SOURCES})
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_proj 
    PRE_LINK
    COMMAND <run objcopy on some of the object files here>
    COMMENT " Running PRE_LINK action "
)
```

I don't see a good way with cmake to get the object file names so that I can loop over some of them and strip out debug symbols from some while leaving debug symbols for other objects. This would then allow me to create a smaller static library with symbols added for only the objects I need.  Is there any cmake variable that can give me all the object file names so I could selectively call objcopy and strip out debug symbols for some of the object files?

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic - static libraries are not linked. The object files are merely archived.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell I think the best you can do is specify a command to run on the entirety of the target, as opposed to just some of the target's object files. For example, to manually strip a static library you could do:

```
add_library(my_proj STATIC ${SOURCES})
add_custom_command(TARGET my_proj POST_BUILD
    COMMAND objcopy -S $<TARGET_FILE:my_proj>
    COMMENT "Stripping my_proj"
)
```

Which will run objcopy on my_proj.a after it has been built. If you need finer granularity on which object files are operated on, I suggest you split up the library into a few smaller static libraries, and operate accordingly on each one.